# Media queries with operational references in LESS

Tags: css, less, media-queries

I want to use a variable to contain a screen resolution, I was thinking about:

```
@myStatement: ~"only screen and (min-width: @myVar - 20px)"
```

and then use `@myStatement` in a media query:

```
@media @myStatement { 
//my properties...
}
```

I've read that in order to reference a variable in a string I have to do something like:

```
"@{myVar}"
```

But that didn't work for my example...

So, how can I make an operation using a variable in a string in LESS?

Comment: You can't directly. At best you'll have to move the arithmetic expression to a separate variable and the use that variable within a string as `"@{myVar}"`. The trick is that constructions like `~"bla bla"` were never meant to be used like this and while `@myStatement: ~"only screen ...` have became widepsread via some popular frameworks they are really nothing but just an accidentally fortunate hack. For more details see [#3059](https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/3059).

Comment: Example: [Hack](http://lesscss.org/less-preview/#%7B%22less%22%3A%22%5Cn%40media%20%40myStatement%20%7B%20%5Cn%20%20%20%20%2F*%20something%20*%2F%5Cn%7D%5Cn%5Cn%40myVar%3A%20100px%3B%5Cn%40anotherVar%3A%20%40myVar%20-%2020%3B%5Cn%40myStatement%3A%20~%5C%22only%20screen%20and%20(min-width%3A%20%40%7BanotherVar%7D)%5C%22%3B%5Cn%22%7D) ...

Comment: ... vs. [Proper Method](http://lesscss.org/less-preview/#%7B%22less%22%3A%22%5Cn%2F%2F%20usage%3A%5Cn.myMedia(%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%2F*%20something%20*%2F%5Cn%7D)%3B%5Cn%5Cn%2F%2F%20impl.%3A%5Cn%5Cn.myMedia(%40styles)%20%7B%20%5Cn%20%20%20%20%40media%20only%20screen%20and%20(min-width%3A%20(%40myVar%20-%2020))%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%40styles()%3B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%7D%5Cn%7D%5Cn%5Cn%40myVar%3A%20100px%3B%22%7D).